# What is the probability of throwing 4 and then winning in craps?

Tags: probability, gambling

Owen plays the following game (craps) involving two fair six-sided die.

-If Owen's first throw is a 7, or 11 he wins immediately
- If Owen's first throw is a 2,3, of 12 he loses immediately
-Any other first throw is Owen's special number
- If the game does not finish on the first throw it continues until Owen throws his special number again
- if at any point after the first throw, Owen throws a 7 he loses immediately.

1) What is Owen's probability of throwing 4 as his special number and then winning?
2)What is Owen's probability of winning?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: So for the first part, Owen's probability of throwing a 4 is (3/36) which reduces to (1/12). But I'm not sure what to do from there.

Comment: You've cleared the first throw. From here, you need to calculate the probability that the next $4$ comes before the next $7$, and then you're done with 1).

Comment: Thanks! How do I do that?